# Loop forever and provide delta time

Tags: javascript, html, loops, timedelta

I'm writing an HTML5 Game Development Javascript framework and I want to provide the user the difference in time between the last tick and the current one.

```
setInterval(tick, 16.6666666);

function tick() {
  update();
  draw();
}
```

That's what I have, but I want to have:

```
while (true) {
  /* Calculate delta time */

  tick(dt);
}

function tick(dt) {
  update(dt);
  draw();
}
```

I tried that, using date.getTime(); to calculate delta time, but Firefox said the script crashed. Obviously, an infinite loop will crash. Got any suggestions for how I can go about this?

I want an infinite loop, that can be stopped with `break`. I want to pass delta time too, but that I know how to do.

Comment: Why do you want an infinite loop? An infinite loop crashes the browser.

Comment: @Bergi he is more then likely coming from a native language like c or c++ where the main loop must continue looping until the game has finished e.g. ( while( isDone == false ){ // run game, calc delta time, set tick speed, etc } )

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just maintain a variable with the time of the last update, and calculate the elapsed time/delta time in `tick` itself.

```
var lastUpdate = Date.now();
var myInterval = setInterval(tick, 0);

function tick() {
    var now = Date.now();
    var dt = now - lastUpdate;
    lastUpdate = now;

    update(dt);
    render(dt);
}
```

Here's a JSBin, though I don't think it's really needed... http://jsbin.com/okimam/10

**EDIT**:
I must point out that `setInterval(tick, 0)` does not necessarily mean that `tick` will be called immediately, with an interval of '0ms' between two calls. It depends on the browser.

Comment: @Rikonator please bear in mind that tick speed is usually used with client and server to describe the tick rate of the server where as delta rate describes the actual delta time, if we want to set tick speed to 60 ticks a second we would make the server thread sleep for 1000 milliseconds

Answer (score 6):

Would like to give my two cents. Usually I use this deltatime method in my games:

```
const perfectFrameTime = 1000 / 60;
let deltaTime = 0;
let lastTimestamp = 0;

function start() {
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

function update(timestamp) {
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
    deltaTime = (timestamp - lastTimestamp) / perfectFrameTime;
    lastTimestamp = timestamp;

    // YOUR FRAME CODE HERE!

}

start();
```

This ensure you will have perfect deltatime (as like Unity deltaTime) so you can scale your times to frame time.

Answer (score 5):

This is what I use:

```js
let lastTick = performance.now()

function tick(nowish) {
  const delta = nowish - lastTick
  lastTick = nowish

  update(delta)
  render(delta)

  window.requestAnimationFrame(tick)
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(tick)
```