# JavaScript game starts fast and slows down over time

Tags: javascript, performance, p5.js

My simple JavaScript game is a Space Invaders clone.

I am using the p5.js client-side library.

I have tried many things to attempt at speeding up the game.

It start off fast, and then over time it get slower, and slower, it isn't as enjoyable.

I do not mean to show every bit of code I have. I am not showing every class, but I will show the main class where everything is happening.

Could someone eyeball this and tell me if you see anything major?

I am new to JS and new to making games, I know there is something called update()
that people use in scripting but I am not familiar with it.

Thank you.

```js
var ship;
var flowers = []; // flowers === aliens 
var drops = [];
var drops2 = [];


function setup() {
 createCanvas(600, 600);
 ship = new Ship();
 for (var i = 0; i < 6; i ++) {
  flowers[i] = new Flower(i * 80 + 80, 60);
 }

 flower = new Flower();

}


function draw() {
 background(51);
 ship.show();
 ship.move();
 shipDrops();
 alienDrops();
 dropsAndAliens();
 dropDelete();
 drop2Delete();
}

 // if 0 drops, show and move none, if 5, etc..
 function shipDrops() {
    for (var i = 0; i < drops.length; i ++) {
    drops[i].show();
    drops[i].move();
  for (var j = 0; j < flowers.length; j++) {
  if(drops[i].hits(flowers[j]) ) {
    flowers[j].shrink();
    if (flowers[j].r === 0) {
     flowers[j].destroy();
    }
   // get rid of drops after it encounters ship
     drops[i].evaporate();
   }
     if(flowers[j].toDelete) {
   // if this drop remove, use splice function to splice out of array
     flowers.splice(j, 1); // splice out i, at 1
     }

  }
 }
  
}

 function alienDrops() {
  // below is for alien/flower fire drops 2
  for (var i = 0; i < drops2.length; i ++) {
   drops2[i].show();
   drops2[i].move();
  if(drops2[i].hits(ship) ) {
   ship.shrink();
   drops2[i].evaporate(); // must evap after shrink
   ship.destroy();
   if (ship.toDelete) {
    delete ship.x;
    delete ship.y;
    } // above is in progress, deletes after ten hits?
   
   }

  }
}

 function dropsAndAliens() {
 var randomNumber; // for aliens to shoot 
 var edge = false;
 
 // loop to show multiple flowers 
 for (var i = 0; i < flowers.length; i ++) {
  flowers[i].show();
  flowers[i].move();
  // ******************************************
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100) );
      if(randomNumber === 5) {
    var drop2 = new Drop2(flowers[i].x, flowers[i].y, flowers[i].r);  
    drops2.push(drop2);
     }

  //**************** above aliens shooting 

  // below could be method, this will ensure the flowers dont 
  //go offscreen and they move 
  //makes whtever flower hits this space become the farther most
  //right flower,
  if (flowers[i].x > width || flowers[i]. x < 0 ) {
   edge = true;
  }

 }
  // so if right is true, loop thru them all again and reset x
  if (edge) {
   for (var i = 0; i < flowers.length; i ++) {
   // if any flower hits edge, all will shift down
   // and start moving to the left 
   flowers[i].shiftDown();
  }
 }



}


function dropDelete() {

 for (var i = drops.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   if(drops[i].toDelete) {
   // if this drop remove, use splice function to splice out of array
    drops.splice(i, 1); // splice out i, at 1
   }

  }

}

function drop2Delete() {
  for (var i = drops2.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   if(drops2[i].toDelete) {
   // if this drop remove, use splice function to splice out of array
    drops2.splice(i, 1); // splice out i, at 1
   }
     }

}


function keyReleased() {
 if (key != ' ') {
 ship.setDir(0); // when i lift the key, stop moving
 } 
}

function keyPressed() {
 // event triggered when user presses key, check keycode
 if(key === ' ') {
  var drop = new Drop(ship.x, height); // start ship x and bottom of screen 
  drops.push(drop); // when user hits space, add this event to array
 }


 if (keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW) {
  // +1 move right
  ship.setDir(1);
 } else if (keyCode === LEFT_ARROW) {
  // -1 move left
  ship.setDir(-1);
 } // setir only when pressing key, want continuous movement 
}
```

Comment: You need to use a deltatime calculation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13996267/loop-forever-and-provide-delta-time

Comment: Your snippet doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of a disconnected snippet that we can't run. Note that this should **not** be your entire project. It should be a small example sketch that just shows the problem without any extra code.

But to figure out what's going on, you need to **debug** your program. You need to find out stuff like this:

- What is the length of every array? Are they continuously growing over time?
- What is the actual framerate? Is the framerate dropping, or does it just appear to be slower?
- At what point does it become slower? Try hard-coding different values to see what's going on.

Please note that I'm not asking you to tell me the answers to these questions. These are the questions you need to be asking yourself. (In fact, you should have all of these answers before you post a question on Stack Overflow!)

If you still can't figure it out, then please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in a new question post and we'll go from there. Good luck.