# JavaScript Delta Timing

Tags: javascript, timedelta

Trying to understand some modified code from [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55028818/2468607). The part that doesn't make sense to me is where does `timestamp` come from in the function `update(timestamp)`? I don't see it defined anywhere.... but the code still works. Just looking for an explanation to better understand things, thanks.

```js
const log = console.log.bind(console);

const perfectFrameTime = 1000 / 60;
let deltaTime = 0;
let lastTimestamp = 0;
let timerState = true;

function start() {
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

function update(timestamp) {
    if (timerState){
      requestAnimationFrame(update);
    }
    deltaTime = (timestamp - lastTimestamp) / perfectFrameTime;
    lastTimestamp = timestamp;
    
    log(deltaTime);



    // YOUR FRAME CODE HERE!

}

setTimeout(()=> {timerState = false;}, 1000);
start();
```

Comment: It is provided by the host environment. See documentation of [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame#parameters).

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame(update)` will wait for the next frame and then call the `update` function with the current timestamp as a parameter

Comment: Any time you see a function reference used as a parameter (`requestAnimationFrame(update)`) the first place to look is the docs for the function taking the reference--it's almost certainly a callback, and its argument is usually documented.